Sous Vide: Why pre-heat?
I wonder why all sous vide recipes call for preheating the bath first and then placing the food inside. I always do the opposite: I place the food in first and then start sous vide cooking.
My reasoning is this: sous vide cooking is controlled by a PID controller. If I place the bag in after the desired temperature is reached, the temperature will drop, which will change the integral factor and cause fluctuations in temperature until the controller readjusts, possibly reaching a higher temperature than desired.
Edit
My self made sous vide uses a PID controller. Heating times to 60°C is 30 minutes in a 3L bath using a 1000 Watts hot plate. Temp oscillation is +/- 0.2° C. Not overshooting is first priority, because it ruin soft boiled eggs (I like them at 65°C). See Serious Eat guide to sous vide eggs.


I don't have an answer to "why" but I want to address your arguments against it. If your temperature drops when adding cold food, you're not using enough water. With a sufficient mass of water relative to the mass of the food, the drop in water temperature will be minimal. Also, a good controller shouldn't overshoot much the water temperature when adjusting, and certainly not to the point where the internal temperature of the still-cold food would overshoot the set point.

You are right; I'm using a 3L pot, and even a 1.5L for small items.

That's maybe not too bad. I used a thermal equilibrium calculator, and it said that if you put a 150 g steak, 4°C, with 2.85 kJ/Kg°C specific heat, into 1.5 l of 54°C water, you can expect thermal equilibrium at 50.81°C. But of course, the meat will cool the water quite slowly - so the controller won't have much trouble giving it heat long before it drops even close to equilibrium.

In case you want to dig more into the physics behind @rumtscho's comment, look up the heat capacity of water. It's the temperature analogy of what inertia is to a moving object. A truck and a ping pong ball can be moving at the same speed, but the ping pong ball will deflect off of you and the truck will barely notice that it demolished you, because of their difference in mass. Heat capacity is the same: two materials can have the same temperature but one can get colder faster than the other one. Water is closer to a truck than a ping pong ball.

Probably too short for an answer: maybe simply because you can prepare whatever you are going to cook while it heats up, so you save time?

Have you measured the temperature and found overshoot a real problem with your setup?  Like if the food is very close to the bottom of the pot, it could get hotter there than the temp sensor the controller uses if that's off to the side?

@PeterCordes. Overshoot and oscillations was a big problem until I got the right PID parameters. Heating from the bottom eliminates any temp gradient without using a pump/agitator.

Not worth an answer, but I simply fill my container with hot tap water and then let my sous vide stick take over from there. I would find 30 minutes for heating up simply too long from a practical perspective.

@AnoE It heats slowly to prevent overshooting, especially when doing soft boiled egg.

If you use a larger pot, your temp will drop less and you'll get less oscillation.  In fact, if you get oscillations enough to hurt a recipe, your controller is probably too peppy.

@ScottSeidman I love challenges. Anyone can made a sous vide with a 20 L pot; I want to do it with 1.5 L one.

Common food-borne pathogens are mostly found on the surfaces of cut pieces of meat. (That's why rare steak is safer than rare hamburger.) If your sous vide bath takes a long time to come up to temperature, that means a long time in the temperature "danger zone" for the surface of your meat, compared to those pathogens being knocked back quite quickly when taken out of refrigeration and added to a hot water bath.
Nevertheless, not everyone waits for the water bath to preheat. If your setup is going to come up to temperature in just a few minutes regardless, then it really isn't going to matter.

Could be addressed with a pre-sear in some situations.

@moscafj yes, but only if you can sear all surfaces, and the edges of something like a steak would be quite hard to do

I’ve seen people use a quick dip in boiling water before sous viding at an especially low temperature, to avoid serious off odors from some sort of thermophilic bug.

Bear in mind you have a relatively powerful heater and a small container. We've done sous-vide in large containers with relatively weak heaters, and they've taken hours to get up to temperature, but didn't have a problem keeping warm when they got there. Having some food slowly crawl through blood heat temperatures over the course of hours is a great ticket to food poisoning.

@DavidMcKee I think that's basically what I said in my answer, is there something you feel is missing?

If the PID parameters are set up properly, overshoot should be very small indeed (ideally comparable to the variation in temperature within the bath, which a circulator can minimise but never eliminate). If they've been auto-tuned on a small volume of water and you add a lot of food, it should still be OK as a reduction in thermal mass is much more likely to cause overshoot via the I term.
If the PID has been hand-tuned, an overly generous I term can cause overshoot; try reducing it and slightly increasing P if that happens

My cheap sous vide wand just does bang-bang control and is completely good enough. The large thermal mass of the water and the nearly immediate response of the heating element means that it's just a very very easy control problem. I can't imagine tuning a PID controller to the point where the food could notice anything amiss.

@Sneftel I think so too, but the OP asserts theirs uses PID.  Of course you can do PID using PWM to vary the power.  If you then reduce the PWM frequency to sub-Hz but actively control the duty cycle rather than just responding to a themostat with a deadband, you end up with a sort of pre-empting bang-bang control that's quite effective if the power per unit heat capacity isn't too high.

@ChrisH. I built my own sous vide. It's an Arduino + TRIAC (zero cross detection). My resolution is half AC cycle. Min power is half cycle ON ever 100 half cycles (50 Hz local frequency). Keep temp +/- 0.2°C

@CandidMoe I've thought about doing something similar, though there's no point in mine being too sophisticated - at least at first it would use a slow cooker which responds inherently very slowly, but I wouldn't be using it for meat.  But I do a lot with PID controls in work (so I know that some, even commercial, controllers can be hard to get right on the integral)

@ChrisH. It was a nice project to learn electronic and get a sous-vide, which were to expensive/unavailable at that time. And PID only doesn't work quite right; I have to add several heuristic to manage border cases.

@CandidMoe that's a reason why I'd like to do it.  My electronics skills are adequate but the first time I design a temperature controller it should be for an application that's self-limiting and with cheap failure modes.

Note this answer refers to a certain type of controller, which is what I have. The OP is using a PID controller, which works differently. I'm adding the note after two people commented on the difference, but not deleting, since there might be other readers with the simpler controller type.

I think that your concern is unfounded. It's not even the small effect size, as I was thinking when I saw your question at first; it's that you're using the completely wrong intuition.
A sous vide PID controller is not a sapient being like the proverbial frog being boiled; it's not even a sophisticated mechanism like, say, your metabolism, where a sudden spike of blood sugar leads to too much insulin release, sending you into an overcorrection which the body then struggles to counter-correct. No - it's a very dumb system, which neither takes into account speed of change, nor has any way of reacting beyond turning the heater to ON.
So let's see what happens with the water temperature when we do it your way, heating the water and the steak together:

Of course you get an overshoot of the selected temperature, up to the point at which the controller is programmed to turn off. When it turns off, the cooling phase starts (which is longer than the heating one, because there is no active cooling, just dissipation into the environment) until you reach the lower set point, and the heating starts again. Note that the diagram is not drawn to any kind of realistic scale, but the temperature boundaries I chose are very typical; you want to only allow a small deviation from the desired temperature before the controller reacts (by turning on or off), and 1/2°C is a common chosen value that works well in practice. (Note that it doesn't mean that the internal temperature of your meat fluctuates by 1/2°C, this is the water bath).
And let's see what happens when we instead start with cold water, wait for it to heat up, and then drop some cold meat inside:

The one big change is that during one fluctuation, the cooling down happens quicker. Also, there should be a bit of change in the slope in later fluctuations too, because the meat is "sucking out" a bit more energy from the water due to higher delta T, but that effect reduces with later fluctuations as the meat temperature rises.
The more interesting thing is, what did not change? A large overshoot didn't. The dumb controller does nothing but turn the heater on when it's at the lower set point, and turn it off when it's at the higher set point. It doesn't act in panic and set the heater to "turbo hyper blast" when it notices a sudden drop in temperature - it is neither capable of detecting a "sudden drop" as opposed to a "slow drop", nor does the heater have a "turbo hyper blast" mode, or any other mode than "on" and "off".
And if you have a PID controller
There is also my earlier point from a comment, that the drop in temperature isn't even all that sudden. If we assume a 150 g steak, 4°C, 2.85 kJ/kg°C, dropped in 1.5 l of water at 54°C, the thermal equilibrium temperature would be 50.81°C, so just over 3°C of a difference - but of course it would take a very long time for the steak to cool the water down, so the drop in temperature won't even be very sudden. As explained in the diagrams, with a threshold controller, this isn't even relevant, since the speed of cooling doesn't affect the fluctuation amplitude. But if you do have a PID controller, the disturbance size becomes relevant, and there the solution is to have sufficient water - as you see, 10:1 is already quite good.

That being said, I'm afraid that I don't have an answer as to why recipes tend to prefer dropping the cold item into hot food. All I can address is the wrong assumption behind your question, and point out the fact that, from the point of view of temperature control, both options are perfectly viable.

PID is capable of varying the power though - that's why we use it over a simple thermostat (whether it actually varies the steady state power or uses pulse width modulation (PWM) to do so doesn't matter if the PWM is fast compared to the time constant of the heat losses)

@ChrisH I admit I don't know how commercial sous vide appliances are programmed. I use a simple thermostat that turns an electric outlet on and off, with the simplest immersive heater possible plugged into that outlet, plus a small aquarium pump that mixes the water. It works great for me, and does exactly what I showed in my drawing. If it's common for sous vide machines to try to be "smarter" than that (although I don't know why they would, since my graph shows it may be counterproductive) then there's still the small effect size to make the concerns unimportant.

Also, another thought: If somebody was sophisticated enough to improve on that, by adding variable power in order to have the system match the ideal temperature more closely, they would hopefully program it in a way that takes into account the danger of overshoot at sudden disturbances, and minimizes that too. This might be wishful thinking, based on my experience with a few cheap cooking appliances which try to do temperature control and fail at it miserably :( but hopefully there are producers who get it right!

I did as you did, but results were unsatisfactory. I opted for a hot plate, no pump/agitator. Heating from below eliminates any temperature gradient in the water.

@CandidMoe interesting! I like the immersion heater because it allows me to vary the container (for example, I used to ferment yogurt in individual small glasses, in a large gastronorm that wouldn't have fit on a hotplate). How were your results unsatisfactory?

An immersion heater requires a propeller o a pump to eliminate temp gradient. That's a mechanical factor that can fail badly. A hot plate has no mechanical parts, is safe to left unattended, and it's quiet.

I can use a bigger pot over the hot plate if I needed.

@rumtscho that's what I'd do, except using my slow cooker as both vessel and heater. That's good enough for yoghurt and eggs anyway, and I don't eat meat.  Of course a slow cooker is underpowered for that application and would definitely need preheating, but the extra hardware would take up no extra storage which is attractive to me

Your graphs appear to be showing a threshold controller, not a PID controller.  PID controllers provide lower fluctuations, but are susceptible to a phenomenon called integral windup where a sudden change (such as would happen if you put cold ingredients in a warm bath) causes a sustained overshoot of the target temperature.

@Mark indeed. I wrote this up because it is correct about the setup I have, and I had made a hasty generalization :) Since you're the second person to point out the difference, I now added a note to clarify that it doesn't always apply. Thank you for the links about the controller types!


I wonder why all sous vide recipes call for preheating the bath first.

Maybe for the same reason why baking recipes call for preheating the oven first. The author doesn't know the details of your setup. They don't know how long it will take to come up to temperature.
You are cooking in a saucepan on a hot plate. Maybe I am cooking with an immersion heater in giant picnic cooler. Even if we both follow the recipe to the letter, we might not get exactly the same results. But, I bet our results will be closer to what the author intended than if the author had told us to plonk the food into "tap cold" water and then switch the heat on.

Sous vide times are much longer and forgiven than oven times, so taking a bit longer to reach temp doesn't really make a difference. Oven times are critical; you either end with a raw meat or a burnt one if you are not careful.

@CandidMoe, Less of a difference still is a difference. And, even if a reason for doing a certain thing in a certain way isn't really as important as most people think, even if the reason is completely wrong, it still can be the answer to "why does everybody do it this way?"

That procedure would just add guesswork.
The amount of time it takes for a sous vide prep to come to temp will depend on the power of the heater, the programming of the controller of the heater, how much water is in the bath, and the temperature of the water at start.
The failure modes for getting it wrong can be bad, and mostly have already been described -- health risks, and food not getting to the desired temp.  The latter seems like it's more of an issue for shorter cook times, and the former, for longer cook times.
